# Cannot resolve method 'addAttribute' in 'Model' i got this error while executing an STS code

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, sts, addattribute

the addAttribute function is not working and is not known for the sts plugins :

```
package com.example.projet.user;


import ch.qos.logback.core.model.Model;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class userController {
    @Autowired private userService service;
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public String showUserList(Model model){
        List<user> ListUsers = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("ListUsers",ListUsers);
        return "users";

    }

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
the pom.xml in my code is ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>projet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projet</name>
    <description>projet</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i tried to add a new dependency to configure the addAttribute and it did not work so i tried then to download new plugin in my IDE and it didn't work as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an import statement which causes the problem.
`import ch.qos.logback.core.model.Model;`
Replace that with `import org.springframework.ui.Model;`

Comment: It would be better to provide the solution to the problem as well not just the reason of the error. `import org.springframework.ui.Model`

Comment: I agree, but I’m on my phone and didn’t memorize the full package name.